# Icecast2 Statistics and/or Client Logging

Tags: php, reporting, icecast, usage-statistics

I'm trying to figure out a way to display statistics for clients connecting to and Icecast server. I think I've got pretty far- but I'm stuck on a few hiccups.

The current setup I have to Icecast is to parse the access.log with awstats. Now, this works, the graphs aren't pretty but it is usable. The problem is there just isn't very much information.

The statistics given by Icecast Admin and XML notes how long users have connected, IP Address, and Client information. This is exactly what I want. The problem with those stats being- They don't log. I can only view who is currently connected, and how long they have been connected.

The last effort I've stumbled on is using the url auth options in the Icecast statistics. This gives me the advantage of launching a php script anytime a user connects or disconnects with all the information I want. Just has to be parsed! Perfect! Except, the authentication forces clients to enter a username/password when connecting to the stream. This greatly limits my connections. Is there a way pass this? Ideally I'd like javascript to handle my audio play back, but I'd like to keep it open to any device and browser for future development.

The option exists where I can poll the server every minute or so to collect connection data, but that really seems like a dirty solution for what could be a "user disconnects and dumps basic information" script and never missing those imperfections and collecting good usable data.

Answer (score 0):

The Icecast access log has an additional column that contains the number of seconds a client was connected. Obviously, this is being logged *after* the client disconnects. Computers aren't clairvoyant.

There is an ancient fork of Webalizer that adds support for such things as listen duration:

http://webalizer.bzhtec.com/

In addition, there are also munin plugins that can do real-time statistics.

http://www.ruecker.fi/foss/icecast/munin-icecast-0.1.tar.bz2

And another plugin I can't remember right now, but it wanted admin level access and I found that eeeew.